# what's the calculation with fillfactor in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
create table big(id integer primary key generated always as identity, s char(1000)) with(fillfactor = 10);

 insert into big(s) values('foo');
 insert into big(s) values('foo');
 select ctid, id from big;
```

return:

```
 ctid  | id
-------+----
 (0,1) |  1
 (1,1) |  2
(2 rows)
```

I don't know how to do calculation with fillfactor, so that  the above table will be structured as one record/row one page?

```
-- return 2064,2
SELECT sum(pg_column_size(t.*)) as filesize, count(*) as filerow FROM big as t; 
--return 1004
select pg_column_size(s) from big; --1004
```

Only info i get from manual.

> **fillfactor (integer)**
> The fillfactor for a table is a percentage
> between 10 and 100. 100 (complete packing) is the default. When a
> smaller fillfactor is specified, INSERT operations pack table pages
> only to the indicated percentage; the remaining space on each page is
> reserved for updating rows on that page. This gives UPDATE a chance to
> place the updated copy of a row on the same page as the original,
> which is more efficient than placing it on a different page. For a
> table whose entries are never updated, complete packing is the best
> choice, but in heavily updated tables smaller fillfactors are
> appropriate. This parameter cannot be set for TOAST tables.

Further reference: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bobgebpb07ctCM-Jk9XBxmY8k9CZkorn/view?usp=sharing Page: 190.

Comment: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I usually use text. I understand this case is  for paddling blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your rows are larger than 10% of one 8kB block, so they end up in different blocks. `char(1000)` is mean, because it is padded with blanks, and the size is to small to trigger TOAST compression.

Comment: 8*1024 =  8192. Let assume only 90% is usable. 8192 *0.8 * 0.1 = 737.28 because 727.28 > 1004 then trigger to split to different block.

Comment: Sounds about right.